# Is Steiner symmetrization "Turing complete"?

Tags: computability-theory, convex-geometry, geometric-measure-theory, turing-machines

This question stems from intuition so it is a little soft. It concerns performing computation using transformations on sets. The idea is that a rearrangement like Steiner symmetrization might be "computationally strong enough" to be used to execute arbitrary programs.

First we probably should pick an appropriate set $\mathcal{B} \subset \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^d)$, maybe the Lebesgue or Borel measurable sets.
Then consider a set of transformations $(T_i)_{i \in I}$ where $T_i: \mathcal{B} \longrightarrow \mathcal{B}$ for every $i \in I$.

We also need a program function $f: \mathcal{B} \longrightarrow I$.
Lastly we need some condition that decides when the program finishes running, formally $E: \mathcal{B} \longrightarrow \{\mathit{True}, \mathit{False}\}$.

Then computation is done as follows:

1. Some $M_0 \in \mathcal{B}$ is the input
2. $M_{n+1} = T_{f(M_n)}(M_n)$
3. If $E(M_n) = \mathit{True}$ then the program stops running and the output is $M_n$

**1. Question:** How are such systems of computation formalized? (i.e. does there exist a "name" for this)

**2. Question:** Can such systems be "Turing complete" in some sense? How would one show this?

I will also give the specific example that made me wonder: $\mathcal{B}$ are the Lebesgue measurable sets and $(T_i)_{i \in I}$ are the Steiner symmetrizations in all directions.
Then $f$ is something I don't know and $E$ could be a condition like the set being convex.

I am sorry for this question being a little vague and would appreciate if someone could improve it.